# Função em Background - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, background

Olá, 
Preciso colocar uma animação na tela, ela só pode ficar visível durante 10 segundos, depois desse tempo ela some, e caso o usuário clique em um botão específico a animação volta.
Alguém pode me ajudar? Não estou conseguindo resolver.

Muito obrigado!

Comment: Você quer que o `progress bar indeterminate` rode em background? E depois de 10s que der o `show` ele suma (ficar rodando em background)? E quando clicar em um botão específico ela reapareça?

Comment: Quero que depois que eu aperte um determinado botão a progress bar apareça e suma depois de 10 segundos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possível solução seria usar a Classe do pacote `java.util`: [`Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html). Com está classe é possível agendar tarefas ou que uma determinada tarefa seja executada em determinados intervalos de tempo ou até então 
agendar a tarefa especificada para execução após o atraso especificado. Nela uso a função [`schedule`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long%29) em uma de suas implementações que recebe 2 parâmetros: [**`TimerTask`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) e **`delay`**.

No seu *XML*:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Mostrar ProgressBar"
    android:id="@+id/button"
/>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    ...
/>

...
```

Aqui no XML adicionei o atributo `android:visibility="gone"` na `View` `ProgressBar` para manter *"escondido"* o elemento!

Na sua Activity:

```
//recupera o Button e o ProgressBar do XML
Button bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
ProgressBar mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

//Evento de click do botão
bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         //Quando clica no botão torna visível o ProgressBar
         mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


         Timer timer  = new Timer();
         timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
             @Override
             public void run() {

                 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                       //Depois que passa os 10s "esconde" o ProgressBar
                       mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                 });
             }
          },10000);//Aqui o delay é um long em milisegundos
      }
});
```

Internamente no método `schedule` uso ainda o método [`runOnUiThread`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) da `Activity` para manipular (esconder) a `View` `(ProgressBar)`,  caso contrário geraria uma `Exception` pelo fato de estar manipulando a UI em segundo plano então com este método move a ação para Thread principal.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta! Me ajudou :D

Comment: De nada! Estamos aqui para ajudar e ser ajudados mesmo.